# Do we need a reception desk for every building?

Tags: theme-hospital

When you buy an expand for your hospital, do you have to place a reception desk with appropriate staff into the new area ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you should not need a reception desk per area. Each reception desk has a maximum queue length, so maybe build one or two in the same building next to each other in the harder levels.

It is best to have your reception desk near your GP offices since the receptionist will direct people there first.

This is may be a better explaination: http://www.eudoxus.demon.co.uk/thc/hospital.htm#receptionist